# Why can I only change one object property in my React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I'm trying to create an interest calculator in React. I can change the value of one property with a slider, but as soon as I change a second property value, the first property is reset to the default value.

Why is that and how to fix it?

```
const CalculatorContext = React.createContext();
const CalculatorProvider = (props) => {

  const calculatorInformation = {
    initial_investment: 10000,
    monthly_contribution: 1000,
    length_of_time_years: 40,
    interest_rate_per_year: 7,

    result: 2636200,
    changeCalculation: (value, property) => {
      setCalcInfo(
        {...calcInfo, [property]: value}
      );
    }
  }
  const [calcInfo, setCalcInfo] = useState(calculatorInformation);

  return (
    <CalculatorContext.Provider value={calcInfo}>
      {props.children}
    </CalculatorContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100000" step="1000" value={context.initial_investment}
        onChange={(e) => context.changeCalculation(parseInt(e.target.value), "initial_investment")}></input>
```

Comment: `calculatorInformation` gets recreated every render. It probably does not belong inside the component body.

Comment: Also you are destructing `...calcInfo` which doesn't even exist at this point. It is defined below the object.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that too, but what's the correct way to handle it?

Comment: I would recommend reading something like this https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is how you are using `useState` hook, it is anti pattern to declare a function inside a state. just move the function outside the state block and every thing should work fine.

```js
const CalculatorContext = React.createContext();
const CalculatorProvider = (props) => {

  const calculatorInformation = {
    initial_investment: 10000,
    monthly_contribution: 1000,
    length_of_time_years: 40,
    interest_rate_per_year: 7,

    result: 2636200,
    
  }
  const [calcInfo, setCalcInfo] = useState(calculatorInformation);
  
  const changeCalculation = (value, property) => {
      setCalcInfo(
        {...calcInfo, [property]: value}
      );
    }
    
  return (
    <CalculatorContext.Provider value={{calcInfo, changeCalculation}}>
      {props.children}
    </CalculatorContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Welcome! I created a Sanbox for it.    https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-cherry-cvdll?file=/src/App.js